# Orientation problem

Tags: android

I developed one application it supports both landscape and portrait.but when i launch my application from another application(Using Intents)orientation is not working(its not rotating when device changes orientation) calling application is supports one orientation(Portrait) is it possible to make my application work in both orientations even it is called from different application which won't support orientation?

Thanks
Shiv

Comment: How did you make sure for the first time that your orientation change is working fine? I mean what changes you are doing when you are launching your application directly from menu screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u set the orientation in the activity in the manifest file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

remove this and check it

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:screenOrientation and add android:configChanges="orientation".This will prevent app from reloading when orientation changes..

Comment: Does he wants the app to be prevented from reloading ? I doubt. I think he wants the orientation change for his activity should happen flawlessly i.e. it should fit perfectly with new screen height and screen width.